# rendering the small columnrange intervalles as png image too

Tags: highcharts

I am rendering 4 columnRange in my HighChart and facing the problem that the small intervalles (one minutes intervall for example A has 12:51-12:52 and 12:56-12:57 ) 
are not being rendered when printing the result as png image. Is there any configuration in HighCharts to get around that?

https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/7288/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',
{
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true,
        height: 192,
        spacingLeft: 10
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null,
        style: {
            "fontSize": "8px"
        }
    },
    subTitle: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 30
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 4,
        categories: ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                "fontSize": "7px"
            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                "fontSize": "6px"
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1800000,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
                x: 1,
                low: 1483336800000,
                high: 1483336860000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483336860000,
                high: 1483337340000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483337340000,
                high: 1483337400000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483337400000,
                high: 1483337700000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483337700000,
                high: 1483339920000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483339920000,
                high: 1483341780000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483341780000,
                high: 1483342260000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483342260000,
                high: 1483345080000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483345080000,
                high: 1483345140000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483345140000,
                high: 1483346400000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483346400000,
                high: 1483346460000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483346460000,
                high: 1483347420000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483347420000,
                high: 1483347600000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483347600000,
                high: 1483347780000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483347780000,
                high: 1483348020000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483348020000,
                high: 1483348200000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483348200000,
                high: 1483352460000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483352460000,
                high: 1483352640000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483352640000,
                high: 1483352700000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483352700000,
                high: 1483353840000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483353840000,
                high: 1483354920000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483354920000,
                high: 1483355160000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483355160000,
                high: 1483359480000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483359480000,
                high: 1483361460000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483361460000,
                high: 1483361520000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483361520000,
                high: 1483361580000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 3,
                low: 1483361580000,
                high: 1483361760000,
                color: '#79d279'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483361760000,
                high: 1483361820000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
            {
                x: 2,
                low: 1483361820000,
                high: 1483362060000,
                color: '#ff9966'
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1483362060000,
                high: 1483364280000,
                color: '#66ccff'
            },
        ]
    }]
}
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase width of the exporting image.

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      width: 1000
    }
  }
},
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/7294/

[image]